# How to insert a value to a column where another column is equal to specific word?

Tags: php, sql

I am currently working on an enrollment website for our research project. How to assign the section of a student where the course is "Computer Programming" limited to 50 per section? I currently have this but don't know what to do:

```
$course= $_POST[course];
    $section= "Kindness";
        $query2 = "SELECT * from students WHERE Specialization= 'Computer Programming'";
        mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
        if($row['Specialization'] == $course){
            $query3 = "INSERT INTO students (Section) VALUES ('$section')";
            mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
        }

}
```

Comment: why in `'` single quote  `if($row['Specialization'] == '$course')`

Comment: oh thank you for pointing that out I forgot to edit

Comment: You want to do UPDATE, not INSERT.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in the same query... but i think you problem is other.. do you can change or insert new students? if you can insert you can do like this:

```
INSERT INTO students (Section)
SELECT
   Section
FROM
   students 
WHERE
    Specialization= 'Computer Programming'
    /* here you can add other filters.. like rownum <= 50 (first 50 rows..)*/
```

But if you can change a value you can use a UPDATE..

I prefere resolve a problem in a one SQL query..

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed it to UPDATE. Thank you for your help I really appreciate this.